# Ridge regression to fight ill-conditioning

Tags: matrices, regression

My lecture notes on ridge regression go as follows:

> The eigenvalues of $(\phi^T \phi + \lambda' I)$ are at least
>   $\lambda'$. Therefore ridge regression improves de condition number of
>   the Gram matrix

So I remind you that ridge regression formula is given by $(\lambda'I + \phi^T \phi)^{-1} \phi^Ty$

I understand the proof of the eigenvalues being at least $\lambda'$ but how does this change the condition number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the matrix $A = \phi^T\phi + \lambda' I$ is symmetric its condition number is given by

$$
\kappa = \frac{|\lambda_\max(A)|}{|\lambda_\min(A)|},
$$

where $\lambda_\max(A)$ and $\lambda_\min(A)$ are the maximum and minimum eigenvalues of $A$ with respect to their moduli, respectively. All eigenvalues of $A$ are of the form $\lambda' + \lambda$, where $\lambda$ belongs to $\sigma(\phi^T\phi) \subset [0,\infty)$ the spectrum of $A$. Therefore,

$$
\kappa = \frac{|\lambda' + \lambda_\max(\phi^T\phi)|}{|\lambda' + \lambda_\min(\phi^T\phi)|}
$$

Observe that by adding $\lambda' > 0$ in the denominator we are no longer dividing by a potentially very small number $\lambda_\min(\phi^T\phi)$, which can drastically reduce the condition number.

Comment: You don't need the absolute value signs around eigvenvalues...